# Planilha do excel:

Tags: javafx

Qual é a formula para encontrar o menor numero, segundo, terceiro, quarto, etc.

```
Numero  
300 Menor numero
300 2º  Menor (Qual é a Formula)
297 3º  Menor
297 4º  Menor
62  5º  Menor
62  6º  Menor
62  
44  
44  
23  
23  
23  
23  
19  
19
```

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta, que mostra os resultados na tela de um programa é isso?

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do excel você pode utilizar a função =MENOR(matriz,k).
Onde matriz é a area onde se encontram os números, e k a posição que você quer, 1 - primeiro, 2 - segundo...